# Whether the field column can support timestamp type in CnosDB?

Tags: cnosdb

Whether the field column can support timestamp type in CnosDB? Whether there is a value that we want to record during use is a timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, timestamp and bigint are the same for fields